# Interesting bitmask puzzle in C++

Tags: c++, binary, redis, puzzle, bitmask

I have an interesting bitmask puzzle problem I need help solving in something. Here is the problem:

```
11010
```

Each bit represents a characteristic of a piece of content. It is stored in Redis. But to query it, we need every combination so that we can pull up the key. So `11010` would yield these combinations:

```
11010
10000
10010
11000
01010
00010
01000
```

Anyone have a solution in C++?

Comment: So basically you need the equivalent of something like `if (search_key  & item_key) != 0) ...` ?

Comment: How do you solve it in n^2? Did you mean 2^n?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a list of up to 2^n values in less than 2^n time?  Seriously?

Comment: It seems like the all-subsets of a set problem. This is an exponential algorithm!

Comment: Ah, see, so all we need to do is make sure that n is small enough. Then 2^n beats n^2. Problem solved.

Comment: @MrLister: that limits it to n=1

Comment: @rhalbersma I know that... that was more or less tongue in cheek. Soms moet je mijn commentaren niet te serieus nemen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Chess Programming Wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Traversing_Subsets_of_a_Set#:%7E:text=Traversing%20Subsets%20of%20a%20Set%20determines%20the%20power%20set%20of,factors%20with%20a%20certain%20cardinality.) for an algorithm that is linear in the number of subsets of the initial bitmask. With n bits set to 1, that number is equal to 2^n, so it's exponential in the number of set bits.

```
// enumerate all subsets of set d
void enumerateAllSubsets(U64 d) {
   U64 n = 0;
   do {
      doSomeThingWithSubset(n);
      n = (n - d) & d;
   } while ( n );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I will read up on this. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1):

If 2^n (n=bits set) is more than the number of keys you have, it might be faster to invert the problem.  That is, get your list of keys and test them against the bitmask instead of enumerating the possible keys and checking for values.